# The number 0 is being returned every time in HealthKit using swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, healthkit, hksamplequery

I have been successfully able to write to HealthKit but receiving these values always return 0. I am trying to return the latest value of weight.

This is the function that I read weight:

```
public func readWeight(result: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    print("Weight")
    let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)

    let weightQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: quantityType!, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) {

        query, results, error in

        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!)
            result(0.0)
        }

        guard let results = results else {
            print("No results of query")
            result(0.0)
            return
        }

        if (results.count == 0) {
            print("Zero samples")
            result(0.0)
            return
        }

        guard let bodymass = results[0] as? HKQuantitySample else {
            print("Type problem with weight")
            result(0.0)
            return
        }
        result(bodymass.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.pound()))
    }

    healthKitStore.execute(weightQuery)
}
```

This is how I set it to a variable:

```
 readWeight() { weight in
     Weight = weight
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the latest HKSampleQuery datapoint in swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849723/get-the-latest-hksamplequery-datapoint-in-swift-3)

Comment: @ninjaproger That is mine... I made it so the question can be a little clearer and it is asked differently

Comment: @arodebaugh if you have the same problem in both questions, then you you should update the first one to be more clear, not open another open.

Comment: @Cristik Made the other one clearer sorry about all this mixup I just really want to continue on this project but this bug is making me unable to do so

Comment: @arodebaugh if you improved the other question, is this one still needed? You can delete it if not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are declaring your variable `bodymass` as the very first element in the array `results[0]`, it must be the last element of the array. Check if your first value for weight is `0` in the Health app, it most likely is because as I said `bodymass` is the first element of `results` or your first value in the Health app. Hope this helps.