# HKSampleQuery will only return values from past 7 days?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos-4

This is a WatchOS App.  Through testing, it appears as though this code will only return any bodyweight values that I manually add to the health app that are less than 1 week old.  Is this intended?  Ways around?

```
func getUserBodyMass(completion: @escaping (HKQuantitySample) -> Void) {

            guard let weightSampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass) else {
                print("Body Mass Sample Type is no longer available in HealthKit")
                return
            }

            //1. Use HKQuery to load the most recent samples.
            let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date.distantPast,
                                                                  end: Date(),
                                                                  options: [])
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate,
                                                  ascending: false)
            let limit = 1
            let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: weightSampleType,
                                            predicate: mostRecentPredicate,
                                            limit: limit,
                                            sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, samples, error) in


                                                //2. Always dispatch to the main thread when complete.
                                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                    guard let samples = samples,
                                                        let mostRecentSample = samples.first as? HKQuantitySample else {
                                                            print("getUserBodyMass sample is missing")
                                                            return
                                                    }
                                                    completion(mostRecentSample)
                                                }
            }
            healthStore.execute(sampleQuery)
    }
```

Comment: Are you running this code on watchOS?

Comment: @Allan yes why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HealthKit on watchOS only provides access to the last week of data. You can use the `HKHealthStore` method [earliestPermittedSampleDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614166-earliestpermittedsampledate) to query for the exact date. If you need to query for historical samples from HealthKit that may be more than a week old, you should do so with your companion iOS app and then send the relevant information to your watchOS app using WatchConnectivity.

Comment: Wish I've found your answer a couple of days before. It's definitely the right answer. I struggled around in searching for something broken inside my app, but at the end turns out that the problem was related to samples date. I manage to solve my problem by pushing the required value through WCSession. So, when the watch doesn't find anything, it could rely at least on a cached value.